# How do to "Showing 1-10 of 728 results"

Tags: php, pagination

I'm wondering on how to output "Showing 1-10 of 728 results" in PHP. Say I have the total rows count, the items per page and the offset, what would be the best way to output that phrase? How would I deal with single results, no results, an offset higher than the total row counts, pages that don't have enough items to be higher than the per page count? I'm a bit lost. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Addition, multiplication and division of those 3 numbers you have. That's all that's involved. You might want to take out a sheet of paper and a pencil and work at calculating the things you want to display in each of the edge cases you mentioned. Make up numbers fitting those situations and calculate the "1-10 of 728" numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called pagination. Here is a solid tutorial: [Pagination tutorial](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)

Comment: Nice tutorial. I wish I'd had that to help me the first time I put together some pagination code!

Comment: Yea, me too... note it isn't by me :) I just found it a bit ago.